# Trigger a Github workflow to run after specified time elapses?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I have two workflows `A.yml` and `B.yml`. When `A.yml` finishes successfully, is there a way to trigger `B.yml` to run, but only after `N` minutes elapse? I know there's `workflow_run` trigger, but it sounds like that would be triggered immediately upon `A.yml`'s completion.

To explain the background for the question: currently workflow A builds the iOS app and uploads it to testflight and then blocks waiting for the submission to appear in the App Store Connect. There is no way around blocking if you want to distribute to external testers. This means that I'm paying for an expensive `macos` runner while it blocks like this. I though about splitting this into two workflows: one that just builds and uploads the app without submitting for review and another that runs 5-10 mins later (average time for build to appear in ASC).

Answer (score 3):

Given your constraints, one possible solution could be to use [`schedule`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule) event for B with the time specified by A workflow:

- **A.yml**

  - Upload...
  - Calculate required time for B given the current UTC time
  - Configure it in B (e.g. using `date` and `yq`) and push a commit
  - Enable B (`gh workflow enable B`)
  - Make sure to ignore B in other workflows against `push`
- **B.yml**

  - Configure it with `on.schedule`
  - A will update B's `cron` value
  - It'll run and perform its work as scheduled

    - Check its docs to have an idea about when it cannot run as scheduled
  - After completion, disable itself (`gh workflow disable ${{ github.workflow }}`)

---

References:

- [`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)
- [`schedule`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule)
- [`gh worklfow`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow) commands
- [Using GitHub CLI in workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows)

Answer (score 0):

You could add this at the end of A.yml workflow :

Windows :

```
- name: Sleep for 60 seconds
  run: Start-Sleep -s 60
  shell: powershell
```

Linux :

```
- name: Sleep for 60 seconds
  run: sleep 60s
  shell: bash
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it, but the goal is to run workflow A as quickly as possible, since `macos` runners are expensive.